# codeigniter dynamic set_rules from array?

Tags: codeigniter

```
$bLangs = array('EN' => 'English', 'RU' => 'Russian');

foreach ($bLangs as $k => $v)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($k."['page_name']", lang('field_name'), 'trim|required');
}
```

Why this always returns error for empty EN[page_name] ?
When I print $_POST everything is ok.

My html from view source is this:

```
Name: <input type="text" name="EN[page_name]" value="ToDo" class="w750" /><br />
Name: <input type="text" name="RU[page_name]" value="ТоДо" class="w750" /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed
     $k."['page_name']"
to
     $k."[page_name]"
and works.